# У меня стоит задача подсчитать сумму всех чисел от 0 до 1000

Tags: c++, компиляция

При компиляции кода, вместо 500500, я получаю 500500000. В чём непосредственно проблема?
https://pastebin.com/LTrDST8z

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x;

    int y;

    int all = 0;

    int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            all = all + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                sum = sum + all;
            }

        }
        cout << sum ;
;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код в самом вопросе текстом, а не по ссылке

Comment: @dIm0n Всё исправил.

Comment: Теперь отформатируйте его нормально

Comment: @dIm0n Всё сделано, форум не берёт за код #include, namespace, и последние дужки.

Comment: Примите правку, всё берёт

Comment: Говорят, что иногда на собесседованиях самым правильным ответом на задание *`"напечатать сумму от 0 до 1000"`*, считают вот такой короткий код -- `#include <cstdio> main () { puts("500500"); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если вы хотите решать задачу не циклами (что в разы быстрее), можете воспользоваться формулой суммы (1000 + 1) * (1000 / 2)=500500
2. Немного не понял зачем вам там вложенный for (там ещё и используется i в всех циклах)
   вот моя версия на циклах

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x;

    int y;

    int all = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        all += i;
    }

    std::cout << all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема во внутреннем цикле. Он не нужен. Фактически вы считаете сумму от 1 до 1000 тысячу раз, что и получаете в результате.